# Sign in Dirichlet's approximation theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-approximation

Fix $\alpha \in \mathbf{R}$. The classical [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) states there exist infinitely many rationals $p/q$ such that
$$
\left|\alpha-\frac{p}{q}\right|<\frac{1}{q^2}.
$$

> **Question.** Fix $\alpha \in \mathbf{R}$. Is it true that there exist infinitely many rationals $p/q$ such that
>   $$
> 0\le \alpha- \frac{p}{q}\ll\frac{1}{q^2}\,\,?
> $$

Comment: What does the $\ll$ mean in this context?

Comment: "There exists an absolute constant $c>0$ such that the inequality $0\le \alpha-p/q \le c/q^2$ holds for infinitely many rationals $p/q$"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this follows from considering the continued fraction of $\alpha$. If $p_n/q_n$ is the $n$th convergent to $\alpha$ and $n$ is odd then

$$ 0\leq  \alpha - \frac{p_n}{q_n} \leq \frac{1}{q_n^2}.$$